# How to parse Inner Loop data in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is the code for filling up data in script.

```
my $sql_query = qq{SELECT * from table_customers};
my $statement = $db_handle->prepare ($sql_query);
$statement->execute();
my @loop_data = ();

while (my @data = $statement->fetchrow_array()) {
    my $sql = qq {SELECT order_id from table_orders where customer_id = ? };
    my $stmt = $db_handle->prepare ($sql);
    $stmt->execute($data[0]);

    my @InnerLoopData = ();
    while (my @InnerData = $stmt->fetchrow_array()) {
        my %InnerData = ('orderid', $InnerData[0]);
        push(@InnerLoopData, \%InnerData);
    }

    my %data = ('id', $data[0], 'name', $data[1], 'address', $data[2], , 'mobile', $data[3], , 'email', $data[4], 'orders', \@InnerLoopData);
    push(@loop_data, \%data);
}

my $json_text = to_json(\@loop_data);
print $json_text;
$db_handle->disconnect;
```

Response will be copied here.

```
$scope.orderList = response;
```

Code for filling data in angular JS.

```
<tr ng-repeat="o in orderList">
    <td> 
        {{ o.id }} <br>
        <b>{{ o.name }}</b><br>
        {{ o.address }} <br>
        {{ o.mobile }} <br>
        {{ o.email }} <br>
        <tr ng-repeat="o1 in o.orders">
            <td>
                {{o1.orderid}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </td>
</tr>
```

It is filling up id, name, address, mobile and email for customer but not orderids for customer.

This is JSON DATA:

```
address: "15633"
email: null
id: "6"
mobile: "7024029545"
name: "vivek"
orders: Array[5]
0: Object
orderid: "8"
__proto__: Object
1: Object
orderid: "10"
__proto__: Object
2: Object
orderid: "27"
__proto__: Object
3: Object
orderid: "28"
__proto__: Object
4: Object
orderid: "117"
__proto__: Object
length: 5
```

How to get the order Ids of customer in angularjs? Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: @Sajeetharan, I have updated the JSON DATA in question.

Comment: Still i dont see any json

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working application for your data.

```
<div ng-repeat="data in myData">
      {{data.address}} - {{data.email}}
       <div ng-repeat="order in data.orders">
           <b>orders:</b><br/> 
           <ul>            
               {{order.orderid}}              
           </ul>
       </div>
   </div>
```

[`ng-repeat Nested`](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/8vrcof55/1/)